# Show that $(\mathbb R,\sigma)$ is discrete topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be the topolgy on $\mathbb R$ for which the interval [a,b), $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ form a base. Let $\sigma$ be topolgy on R such that $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ and  also (a,b] $\in \sigma$ . Then the space $(\mathbb R, \sigma  )$ is discrete .

Comment: You probably mean that *all* subsets of the form $(a,b]$ are in $\sigma$? In that case you're right.

Comment: Henno Brandsma : yes, all the subset of the form (a,b] are in $\sigma$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in\mathbb R$. Then $(a-1,a],[a,a+1)\in\sigma$. It follows that $\{a\}=(a-1,a]\cap[a,a+1)\in\sigma$. Hence singletons are open in $\sigma$.

Can you use this to now prove that $(\mathbb R,\sigma)$ is discrete?

Comment: @Brain Fitzpatrick : Thank you so much for your prompt reply.